# A plugin to validate a field depending on another field's value

Tags: plugins, validation

I have an Assets field which I want to be required only if a separate Lightswitch field on the same Entry is 'on'. I'm currently trying to implement this with a simple plugin that creates a custom field type ([along these lines](https://github.com/rally-agency/Craft-Unique-Text-FieldType)).

However, in my Field Type's `validation()` method I can't work out how to access the Lightswitch field's value on this same Entry, in order see if it's 'on' or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your FieldType you have `$this->element` available, representing the Element the field is in. If you use `$this->element->lightSwitchHandle` you can access its value.

Comment: Oh! So much simpler than I thought. I'd been scouting through Craft's code looking at ways to loop through the Entry's fields etc. Thanks. (Coincidentally, just as your answer popped up I was reading your Import plugin!)

Comment: Although, having tried this... in order to ensure the Assets field is used when the Lightswitch is 'on', my custom field type needs to be a child of Lightswitch, and that needs to check the Assets field is set. I can't work out how to check if it has any Assets set.

Comment: I think I stumbled on the answer: `$this->element->[assetsHandle]->total()`.

Comment: That is correct